# Implement searching in a generic repository with Linq Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework and Code first. Here is a simple example to show you my case.

```
public class PersonEfModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }
}

public class EfContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Personen { get; set; }
}
```

to be independent from the implementation of the data access i wrote a abstraction layer with repositories.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenericRepository<T>
{
    int Count { get; }

    void Add(T item);
    void Delete(T item);
    void Update(T item);

    T GetData(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetData();
    IEnumerable<T> GetData(int offset, int count);

    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> Find(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicates);
}
```

`Person` and `PersonEfModel` has to be two different types in order to be completely independent from the database models. So there would be a generic Repository of type Person but i dont really know how to implement the Find methods. I can only execute Expressions against the database that depends on the PersonEfModel and not on Person.

So is there a way to translate a `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` into a `Expression<Func<PersonEfModel, bool>>` to execute it against the database or am i on the wrong path?

Comment: You don't need to create 2 objects to represent the same entity. Currently `Person` has no concept of the underlying data access - it is already independent from the database model.

Comment: What problems are you actually facing? Have you tried something? If so, could you share some code?

Comment: look when you load a entity with the EntityFrameworkContext and then make some changes like Person.Name = "Test" than the next time you call SaveChanges on the context the Persons name is "Test" so entity framework is tracking changes from every loaded entity.    I actually tried something (stepping through expression trees and something like that) but nothing worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are truly following domain-driven design then you don't need to create 2 separate objects to represent `Person`. Your `Person` class is already a POCO and it represents the exact entity you need in your own code (you are using Code First after-all).

You are just introducing extra and completely unnecessary complexity. Every time you change your `Person` class you will need to change your `PersonEfModel` class and to get the repository working you will need to use some kind of mapper (AutoMapper) and map `Person` to `PersonEfModel` which is completely unnecessary as the 2 will most likely be identical.

Comment: ok maybe you are right. but there is some kind of overhead in the PersonEfModel. All the ForeignKey properties for example i dont want them in my model. If there is no way to convert between these two expression types i will accept this as answer thanks